# Display new BLE data without button press

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to display new data advertised by a bluetooth low energy (BLE) service. This is done using the setCharacteristicNotification() callback in BluetoothLeService like so:

```
mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, 
   true);
```

, where mNotifyCharacteristic is a BluetoothGattCharacteristic object

This callback is normally triggered inside an onClickListener but I'm trying to display the new data automatically without having to press a button on the UI. I've tried calling this method inside onResume() like so, but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  ...     

  if(mBluetoothLeService != null){

    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic,
      true);        
  }
}
```

I'm an experienced Android Developer but new to Bluetooth so I'm a bit lost here.

Can anyone help?

Cheers,
Tony

Comment: why you need use BluetoothLeScannerCompat for scan ble device. by using this you can get advertised data.

Comment: I solved this problem. I need an initial onClickListener to know what data to display. I put a runnable object inside this listener and can now automatically update the display when new data is advertised